# Get the authority of the user at the time of deleting it in jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

I need to get the authority of the user which I am going to delete. My attempt as follows.

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{login:" + Constants.LOGIN_REGEX + "}")
@Timed
@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.LECTURER})
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable String login) {
    log.debug("REST request to delete User: {}", login);
    boolean hasAuthorityAdmin = false;
    boolean hasAuthorityMember = false;
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
    hasAuthorityAdmin = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN));
    hasAuthorityMember = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.MEMBER));
    if (hasAuthorityAdmin) {
        // delete user
        userService.deleteUser(login);
    } else {
        if (hasAuthorityMember) {
            // delete user if it is a student
            if (**x**.contains(AuthoritiesConstants.STUDENT)) {
                userService.deleteUser(login);
            }
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert("userManagement.deleted", login)).build();
}
```

There instead of x I need a method to retrieve it? That means I need to retrieve the authority which I am going to delete. So anyone have idea. This is inside the userResource.java. Can anyone help me with the code?

[image]

Suppose that I am logged in as an member. Then I am going to delete student. So when I am click the delete button of the student record, should be able to get the ROLE_STUDENT via a method.

Comment: *instead of x I need a method to retrieve it* -- which one you want to retrieve ?

Comment: I need to get the authorities list which assigned to a user whoever I am going to delete

Comment: I think you should pull the user-role info from db. `SecurityContextHolder` are tied with `ThreadLocal` so no way to retrieve without hitting the database.

Comment: can you help me with the code? I have less knowledge

Comment: I didn't have knowledge about your db schema. Perhaps, the process could be : **pull role by user id from userRole table-> check the role exist or not-> decide to delete**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
if (hasAuthorityMember) {
    Optional<User> user = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login);
    Set<Authority> currentUserAuthorities = user.get().getAuthorities();
    for(Authority auth : currentUserAuthorities) {
        // delete user if it is a student
        if(auth.getName().equals(AuthoritiesConstants.STUDENT)) {
            userService.deleteUser(login);
        }
    }
}
```

With UserService, you get the user and his authorities thanks to its login, and for each of its authorities (if there are many), we check the name of the authority. If corresponds to Student, you then delete the user.